# How to keep value after post request?

Tags: php, forms, cookies

I want to learn how to keep value after a post request.

In my code, I have these variables:

1. myvar
2. myans
3. result

`myvar` is a random val between 0-5.  I will get `myans` from my input if `myans == myvar`, then result will be true (else it will be false).

I see `myvar` before I submit my ans just for trying, but although I see the var when I send it, what I see it is sometimes false and sometimes true. What am I missing?

`example.php`:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['result'])) {
        setcookie("result","EMPTY");
    }

    setcookie("myvar",rand(0,5));

    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        if ($_POST['myans'] == $_COOKIE['myvar']) {
            setcookie("result","TRUE");
        }
        else {
            setcookie("result","FALSE");
        }
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <?php echo $_COOKIE['myvar'] ?>
        <input type="text" name="myans">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <?php echo $_COOKIE['result'] ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were having was caused by your random number generator making creating a new number before comparing to the original. I made some changes to only set "myvar" if it's empty. this will only set it once, but at least you can see your code working as intended. I recommend you plan out what exactly what functionality you want before adding to it.

I also switched you out from the "$_COOKIE" var to "$_SESSION" vars. They are hidden from the client, and by php default last about 24 minutes if not refreshed. I don't know what you plan on using this for, but using cookies allows the end user to manipulate that info. If this is not a concern for you, by all means just uncomment the "setcookie()" lines.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['result'])) {
        //setcookie("result","EMPTY");
        $_SESSION["result"] = "EMPTY";
    }

    //setcookie("myvar",rand(0,5));
    if(empty($_SESSION["myvar"])){
        $_SESSION["myvar"] = rand(0,5);
    }
    //

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if ($_POST['myans'] == $_SESSION['myvar']) {
            //setcookie("result","TRUE");
            $_SESSION["result"] = "TRUE";
        } else {
            //setcookie("result","FALSE");
            $_SESSION["result"] = "FALSE";
        }
    }

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    <?php echo isset($_SESSION['myvar']) ? $_SESSION['myvar'] : ""; ?>
    <input type="text" name="myans">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <?php echo isset($_SESSION['result']) ? $_SESSION['result'] : ""; ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```